# vb .net search AD and get samaccountname by filtering employeeID property

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I can't seem to load do anything with the employee id using this code

```
Private Sub AAA(badge As String)
    Console.WriteLine("AD search for " & badge)
    Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=contoso,dc=com", "username", "password")
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(employeeid='" + badge + "'))"
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("EmployeeID")
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")

    Dim results As SearchResultCollection = searcher.FindAll()
    Console.WriteLine("Results: " & results.Count)
    For Each result As SearchResult In results
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0))
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("cn")(0))
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("employeeID")(0))
        'list fields
        For i As Integer = 0 To result.Properties.Count
            Console.WriteLine(result.Properties.PropertyNames(i))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I have tried removing `(employeeid=' + badge +')` from filter and list all users to display each users employee id and maby loop through them but no luck

this code returns samaccountname, cn, adspath (which i didn't ask for) but no employeeid

There is one user who has an employee id value and i can get the user using the following powershell command

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=*)"
```

Can anyone see the error?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around the `badge` value in the filter: `searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(employeeid=" + badge + "))"`.

Comment: Filter is correct (without single quotes).
I have tried using that filter (final string value) in ADUC custom earch, and it works -  but vb .net doesn't find anything.

Comment: Problem is also that using
**searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("EmployeeID")**
doesn't return that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remembered that, a few years ago, I have written a simple AD query&export tool for ad that also shows a complete list of LDAP fields and when I ran it just now, I saw the EmployeeID field in the list.
Here is the code that I used to solve the (current) problem.

```
    Dim searcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & Environment.UserDomainName), "(&(objectCategory=person)(employeeid=" + badge + "))")
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("EmployeeID")
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
    Dim foundUser As SearchResultCollection = searcher.FindAll
    For Each result As SearchResult In foundUser
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0))
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("cn")(0))
        Console.WriteLine(result.Properties("employeeID")(0))
    Next
```

I don't know why, but passing the filter at initialization works properly.
I am also not passing the username and password to the DirectoryEntry object (even though the user that I was using is in the **Domain Administrators group**.

Answer (score 0):

How to use below PowerShell code in the VB.net directory searcher.filter option

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"}
```